# Getting The application must supply JDBC connections exception

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am getting Application must provide JDBC connection exception while trying to perform query on Mysql DB using Spring+hibernate

Application context has following entry

```
<bean id="jdbc" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="appDataSource" />      
</bean>

<bean id="appDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/appdb" />
        <property name="username" value="username" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
```

And JNDI name as

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="appDataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/Modeling"/>
```

Complete stack trace

```
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:44)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:84)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:    )
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1927)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1896)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1874)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2610)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2593)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2422)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2417)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1339)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:964)
```

Hibernate configuration

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping resource="service.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Service.hbm.xml file

```
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="service.repository.Account"
        table="ACCOUNTS" discriminator-value="null">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.Long">
        //all other entry
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: please share your hibernate configurations

Comment: Post the spring configuration of hibernate... Not the hibernate xml files. I also fail to see how setting the datasource to a `JdbcTemplate` is relevant for your question as that is about hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Do the below -

1)check hibernate.cgf.xml(or your hibernate config file) & confirm if below are correct -

```
hibernate.connection.url
hibernate.connection.username
hibernate.connection.password
hibernate.dialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class
```

2) Check for the datasource name you have define in your standalone.xml(JBoss config file).It should match with your jndi-name ="java:**datasource_name**"

Answer (score 0):

I assume your "java:comp/env/jdbc/Modeling" JNDI name does not point to a valid data source object.

Comment: You mean this JNDI name should be same as the mentioned in the jboss standalone xml file?

Comment: I guess the one in the JBoss's standalone xml is the default that you can override somewhere. Sorry, can't provide more details since I never worked with JBoss. But from Spring/Hibernate point of view the fact that UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl is used means that your data source is not returned by jndi-name "java:comp/env/jdbc/Modeling"

Comment: I never worked with Spring. I know EJB+Hibernate. Worked with persistence.xml before. This whole thing is pretty new to me. Forking the project with little doc is very difficult to debug

Comment: I mean check the JBoss configuration console, you should find the data source name. It is not a Spring or Hibernate issue. E.g. see https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/DataSource+configuration

Comment: Yes, it should match with your datasource name in standalone.xml file

Comment: Thanks for the help. It turns out jrebel was messing with the server. Removed jrebel now everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved after removing Jrebel plugin from server settings.
Some how jrebel was messing with the configuration.

Upgraded rebel configuration and things are working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If not resolved yet them try giving path of hibernate.cfg.xml to configure object

cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

and also can skip **dialect** property in xml if you are not able to select right one for yourself .
it worked for me.